# Django-Filter FilterSet Show Only User Generated Objects

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-filter

I'm using a django-filter form and it's filtering all objects for 'associated_portfolios' how can I make it so it only shows the user the objects they created?

Error message:

```
'StatsFilter' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

Filters.py

```
class StatsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    associated_portfolios = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=associated_portfolios)

    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = ['type', 'asset', 'symbol', 'broker', 'patterns', 'associated_portfolios']

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StatsFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['associated_portfolios'].queryset = Trade.objects.filter(user=request.user)]
```

views.py

```
class StatsView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = Trade
    template_name = 'dashboard/stats.html'
    filterset_class = StatsFilter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        filter = StatsFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = filter
        context['get_users_trades'] = Trade.objects.get_users_trades('tj3admin')
        context['get_largest_winning_trade'] = filter.qs.aggregate(max_value=Max('profit_loss_value_fees'))['max_value']
        return context
```

Comment: You should access the fields using the classmethod `get_fields` and that likely solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, still no luck though after changing it to self.get_fields()['associated_portfolios'] = Portfolio.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, now I remember: set the queryset argument of `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` to a callable that accepts request as it's only argument:

```py
def portfolio_filtered_queryset(request):
    return Trade.objects.filter(user=request.user)

class StatsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    associated_portfolios = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=porfolio_filtered_queryset)

The view:
class StatsView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = Trade
    template_name = 'dashboard/stats.html'
    filterset_class = StatsFilter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Must pass in request!
        filter = StatsFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset(), request=self.request)
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = filter
        context['get_users_trades'] = Trade.objects.get_users_trades('tj3admin')
        context['get_largest_winning_trade'] = filter.qs.aggregate(max_value=Max('profit_loss_value_fees'))['max_value']
        return context
```

In `django_filters.filters.QuerySetRequestMixin.get_request()` the request instance is obtained from the parent. But I see no logic in `django_filters.filterset.BaseFilterSet` or concretes that tries to obtain the request through other means. So you must pass the request to the StatsFilter if you wish to make use of QuerySetRequestMixin.

Comment: Thanks again for the attempt and I think we're going in the right direction as I have tried this route before as well. The only issues is now I'm getting the error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: That's because you're not passing the request to `StatsFilter1()`'s constructor.

Comment: I wish.. fixed that type already, was an identical testing form (good catch though)

Comment: Updated, it's not that you instantiated the wrong type, but you do not pass in the request.

Comment: You, my friend, are a legend haha now that a re-read your comment it makes way more sense. I've tried so many workarounds for the last few hours and the answer was so simple.. Thanks a lot for the help!